# Не получается поменять стиль в директиве ngStyle

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

В шаблоне в директиве ngStyle добавляю стиль по условию что переменная day_active_border из компонента равна переменной day из ngFor

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <th *ngFor="let w of days.weekDay">{{w}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let tr_day of days.tr_day" >
        <td
          (click)="dateClick(day)"
          [ngClass]="{'today_day': day !== null && day.toDateString() == classDate.toDateString(),
          'day_active': day !== null && day_active_border == day, 'day': day !== null}"
          *ngFor="let day of tr_day">{{day | date: 'd'}}
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

В компоненте в методе dateClick присваиваю day_active_border значение переменной day

```
  dateClick(day){
    //действие при клике на дате
    if(day == null){
      return;
    }
    this.day_active_border = day;
    this.toParentDate.emit(day);
  }///
```

Но если я меняю значение переменной через @Input() из родительского компонента, то ничего не происходит, хотя приходит объект даты и в методе dateClick присваиваю тот же объект даты а сравниваю в директиве. 
В чем проблема подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Все гениальное просто, спустя неделю скитаний по интернету догадался что в директиве ngClass нужно было сравнить с помощью `.toDateString()` =)